# Javascript functions not working in Grails

Tags: javascript, grails

I am having difficulty trying to understand why the following piece of code does not work:

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <g:javascript library='jquery' plugin='jquery' />
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getNextIndex(){
        return 0;
    }
    function getReadyForNextRow(){
        var $span = $('#next-row');
        var $copy = $span.clone();
        $span.removeAttr('id');
        $copy.html('');
        $copy.insertAfter($span);
        var $Count = $('#count');
        $Count.val(parseInt($Count.val())+1);
    }
</script>
<div>
    <g:hiddenField name="Count" value="${list.size()}" id = "count"/>
    <div class="buttons">
        <g:actionSubmit class="add" value="Add Row"
                        onclick="${remoteFunction(controller: 'Controller', action: 'nextAction', update: 'next-row', params: '\'index=\'+getNextIndex()', onSuccess: 'getReadyForNextRow()')}"/>
    </div>
    <span id = "next-row"></span>
</div>
```

As far as I can tell, it is unable to recognize the javascript function getNextIndex() or getReadyForNextRow(). I have no idea why. I have noticed in my attempts to debug that as a result, the remote function is not calling the controller action function. However, if I replace

```
params: '\'index=\'+getNextIndex()'
```

with

```
params: '\'index=0\''
```

it is able to call the controller's action function. I do not want to use this as a solution as I want (in the future) for getNextIndex() to return different values instead of just 0.

I am open to suggestions as to why this code does not work.

(Please to not comment on naming conventions as I have deliberately changed the names from my actual code for the purposes of this example.)

Comment: You can't pass javascript values directly into `grails` functions in the JS world

Step back for a moment and try this:
`
    <script>
    var action="something"
    var url = "${g.createLink(controller:'something', action:'+action+')}"
    console.log(url);
    </script>
`
vs

 `   <script>
    var action="something"
    var url;
    if (action=="something") {
       url = "${g.createLink(controller:'something', action:"something")}"
    }
    console.log(url)
    </script>
`
Hope it makes sense

Comment: @vahid Thank you for the suggestion, but I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?  The remoteFunction tag has been deprecated.  I switch to using jquery ajax instead.

Comment: @Joe  I am using grails 2.2.4. I will try your suggestion and attempt to use jquery ajax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33325965/grails-gsp-accessing-variables-within-script  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093278/how-do-you-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-your-groovy-controllerhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899107/how-i-access-a-variable-from-javascript-and-grails https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182054/how-can-i-access-a-grails-variable-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion given by Joe, I used a jquery ajax instead. It works as expected now. Here is the updated code:

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <g:javascript library='jquery' plugin='jquery' />
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "${g.createLink(controller: 'Controller', action:'nextAction')}" ,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {index: getNextIndex},
            update: "next-row",
            success:function(data,textStatus){
                jQuery('#next-row').html(data);
                getReadyForNextRow();
            }
        });
    }
    function getNextIndex(){
        return 0;
    }
    function getReadyForNextRow(){
        var $span = $('#next-row');
        var $copy = $span.clone();
        $span.removeAttr('id');
        $copy.html('');
        $copy.insertAfter($span);
        var $Count = $('#count');
        $Count.val(parseInt($Count.val())+1);
    }
</script>
<div>
    <g:hiddenField name="Count" value="${outsideLocations.size()}" id = "count"/>
    <div class="buttons">
        <g:actionSubmit class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow(); return false;"/>
    </div>
    <span id = "next-row"></span>
</div>
```